# Ninject: How to access root object of NamedScope from factory

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

In my application I am using Ninject and the NamedScopeExtension. One of the objects deeper in the object graph needs access to the root object that defined the named scope. It seems to me that `DefinesNamedScope()` does not also imply `InNamedScope()` and instead a new root object is created when I request the root.

Example:

```cs
using System;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope;
using Ninject.Syntax;

namespace NInjectNamedScope
{
    public interface IScopeRoot
    {
        Guid Guid { get; }
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public interface IFactory
    {
        Guid Guid { get; }
        IOther CreateOther();
    }

    public interface IOther
    {
        void SayHello();
    }

    internal class ScopeRoot : IScopeRoot
    {
        private readonly IFactory m_factory;
        private readonly IResolutionRoot m_kernel;
        public Guid Guid { get; private set; }

        public ScopeRoot(IFactory factory, IResolutionRoot kernel)
        {
            m_factory = factory;
            m_kernel = kernel;
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ScopeRoot.DoSomething(): Entering");
            Console.WriteLine("ScopeRoot GUID: {0}", Guid);
            Console.WriteLine("IFactory  GUID: {0}", m_factory.Guid);
            var other = m_factory.CreateOther();
            Console.WriteLine("ScopeRoot.DoSomething(): Other created");
            other.SayHello();
            Console.WriteLine("ScopeRoot.DoSomething(): Exiting");
        }
    }

    internal class Factory : IFactory
    {
        private IResolutionRoot m_kernel;

        public Guid Guid { get; private set; }

        public Factory(IResolutionRoot kernel)
        {
            m_kernel = kernel;
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        public IOther CreateOther()
        {
            return m_kernel.Get<IOther>();
        }
    }

    internal class Other : IOther
    {
        private readonly IScopeRoot m_root;
        private readonly IFactory m_factory;

        public Other(IScopeRoot root, IFactory factory)
        {
            m_root = root;
            m_factory = factory;
        }

        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Other.SayHello(): Hello");
            Console.WriteLine("Our IScopeRoot has GUID: {0}", m_root.Guid);
            Console.WriteLine("Our IFactory has GUID:   {0}", m_factory.Guid);
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();

            kernel.Bind<IScopeRoot>().To<ScopeRoot>().DefinesNamedScope("RootScope");
            kernel.Bind<IFactory>().To<Factory>().InNamedScope("RootScope");
            kernel.Bind<IOther>().To<Other>().InNamedScope("RootScope");

            var root = kernel.Get<IScopeRoot>();
            root.DoSomething();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, `Other` is receiving the same instance of `Factory` as the root does, but a new instance of `ScopeRoot` is created instead of injecting the existing instance that defined the named scope.

How can I access the root of the named scope in a factory? Please note that this example is simplified. In reality, there are several layers of objects between the scope root and the factory method, so I cannot simply pass `this` to the factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're right, out of the box Ninject can't do `.DefinesNamedScope().InNamedScope()`. Except maybe for late "creation" (factory, lazy) this couldn't work anyway, because it would create a cyclic dependency.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to create a "root of the root"... well just one class `ActualRoot` which is bound with `DefinesNamedScope()` and gets an `IRootScope` injected, which again will be bound with `.InNamedScope()`. The bad thing about this is, that you will need to inject/`Get<>` an `ActualRoot` instead of a `IRootScope`.

As far as i remember, what you can also do instead, is:

```
Bind<IRootScope>().To<RootScope>()
    .InNamedScope(scopeName);
```

and then retrieve it as follows:

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<IRootScope>(new NamedScopeParameter(scopeName));
```

This way you don't need a `DefinesNamedScope()`.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm, thank you very much! The second suggestion (`IBindingRoot.Bind<IRootScope>().To<RootScope>().WithParameter(new NamedScopeParameter(scopeName));`) did not work, so I took the liberty of removing it from the answer.